# Permission to user.name(1)/repository.git denied to user.name(2)

Tags: git, github, macos, консоль, permissions

Есть проблема: нет прав доступа для того, чтобы запушить изменения в репозиторий github.

---

Permission to user.name(1)/repository.git denied to user.name(2)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

---

Ранее пользовался другим аккаунтом на github, потом создал другой.
Для каждого сгенерирован свой ssh.

Я не совсем понимаю, как на mac OS управлять учетными данными git?
Как сделать так, чтобы я точно понимал, от чьего лица я пытаюсь запушить что-то? и чтобы таких ошибок прав доступ не возникало?

Answer (score 0):

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user.name/repository.git

вот, что помогло